# how to rehash mongodb ShardKey

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I find a command "refineCollectionShardKey" which can rehash the shard key. But my mongodb's version is 4.0.12. I want to know the rehash command in 4.0.12.

Comment: command is available only for mongoDB version >=4.4 -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/refineCollectionShardKey/